# site.lvh.me redirects to wrong portal after moving DNN site from production to localhost

Tags: localhost, dotnetnuke, alias, portal

I have a production site on DNN 6.2.5 that runs fine. It contains Portal 0 (never used, just a remnant from a previous developer's efforts) and Portal 1, which is the live site.

I moved it to localhost, where I had a previous version working exactly as I wanted. After the move, I went into SQL Server Management Studio and updated the PortalAlias table so that my URLs (localhost/sitename and sitename/lvh.me) point to Portal 1.

Now, when I try to access localhost/sitename, I get Portal 0 and when I call up sitename.lvh.me, I get a message informing me that 'Domain Name Does Not Exist' In The Database.' But it does. And the proper bindings exist in IIS, as it worked before.

I restarted IIS, restarted the system, made a minor change to web.config to force it to update the cache, etc... But there is no way to get into Portal 1, and I can't log into Portal 0 at all to access the DNN dashboard.

Can anyone help me get DNN to 'point to' Portal 1 as I want?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a new portalsetting that contains "default" alias information. You might check out the PortalSettings table to see if you see that URL anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Much appreciated. That helped put me on the right track. I think it was that none of the existing aliases matched the new machine, so it defaulted to that old site. I added the new Site Aliases in DNN before backing it up, moved it to the new machine and deleted the old Site Aliases in SSMS.